# Attaching 2 images in c# using opencv

Tags: c#, image, opencv

I have 2 images, and I'd like to attach image1 on image2. 
The are represented as images like so :

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("2.jpg");
Image<Bgr, Byte> image2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("4.jpg");
```

Say image2 is small, and I want to put it in x,y coordinates of image1, so that they'll be a small square representing image2 on image1 at a specific point.
I tried using copy method, but couldn't do it because it has no coordinates option.

Which function from this library should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a third image which has enough size to hold image 1 + image 2 together.. Let say image 1 width:600px height:600px and image 2 width:50px height:50px..
So if you want to add second image below of image 1, create a new empty image with size 
width:600 and height:650px.. Then just copy the image 1 to first 600x600 part after that you also should copy tha raw data of image 2 to last 50x50 part of third image (600x650)..

Comment: thanks, but i couldn't find any function that does it in image class. 
i want to add the image in a specific location, and all that i found don't have an option to add image to an image at a specific location..